# Android Device, Internal Disk Space runs out real quick

Tags: android, debugging, memory-leaks

I'm having a problem with one of the applications I'm developing.

So far, I'm using USB Debugging mode to install/update the app in my Android device, that's a Huawei MediaPad 7 Lite (Android ICS 4.0.3).

The app is using (According to the Internal Storage in Applications menu) 4.91 MB.

We've been testing it, and the disk space is being consumed by a 1GB per week ratio... Waaaay too much space.

I've checked my application and couldn't find at first sight a memory leak. I've searched a lot, and in a very few places, I've seen that turning USB Debugging off helps.

My question is...

Can this be caused by logging or other functionality I don't know of in the "USB Debugging Mode", or is definitely a coding problem on my side?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried compiling it in not debug mode?

Comment: Thank you for your response, and sorry for taking so long to reply. I found the problem... The system was saving GPS logs, apparently, only some devices have this option enabled, so we needed to root the device, and disable that parameter. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes with the OS itself.

Android has the option to log all the GPS information, apparently, this is only enabled on some devices.

The solution is to disable this GPS log, the device needs to be rooted and you need to edit the file located in /system/etc/gps/glconfig.xml

Find the block

```
<hal
acPortName="/dev/ttyS3"
IBaudRate="115200"
cLogEnableInitState="true"
cLogEnabled="true"
acLogDirectory="/data/gps/log/"
acNmeaOutName="/data/gpspipe"
ctrlPipe="/data/gps/glgpsctrl"
acNvStoDir="/data/gps/"
ItoFileName="Ito2.dat"
/>
```

All we need to change is the line cLogEnabled="true", make it false, and that's it.